# Props not updated

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm a new user of React and I try to dispatch a modification from my redux store into my components through a container component and props.
My problem is at the end, the data isn't updated. I tested and I figured out that in a **Board** component, I got the correct edited state (I edit a module's name in this.state.mlodules[1].name) but this value isn't sent in the **Bloc** component. Here is the render function of my **Board** component:

```
render() {
    const modules = this.state.modules.map((module) => (
        <Draggable key={module._id} x={module.position.x} y={module.position.y} inside={this.state.inside}>
            <Bloc module={module} editModule={this.props.onModuleEdited(module._id)}/>
        </Draggable>
    ));

    return (
        <div className="board"
             onMouseLeave={this.mouseLeave}
             onMouseEnter={this.mouseEnter}>
            {modules}
        </div>
    );
}
```

And here is the render function of my **Bloc** component (I'm using a BlueprintJS editable text):

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="pt-card pt-elevation-3 bloc">
            <span onMouseDown={this.preventDrag}>
                <EditableText
                    className="name"
                    defaultValue={this.props.module.name}
                    onChange={this.nameChanged}
                />
            </span>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Any ideas ?
Thanks !

Comment: how do you assign a value for `<EditableText />`? it seems that you are only passing a `defaultValue` and what does `this.nameChanged` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i mentioned in my comment, you are assigning a `defaultValue` and not assigning a `value` prop.
according to their [source code on line #77](https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/blob/master/packages/core/src/components/editable-text/editableText.tsx#L77) you can see that there's a `value` prop.

Edit: As you can see in the docs, `defaultValue` is uncontrolled input where's `value` is a controlled input
[image]
[image]

Comment: You are right about the defaultValue. But my problem is that I can't edit my field. I think it's because every time I type something, It re-render the component. However, the name value that I obtain from the parent component doesn't change that's why I can't "edit" this field. Why do I get the wrong value for the name ?
**Edit**: I find the answer. I was misundertound the basics of "controlled components" (using the state and the event handler onChange). Thank you !

Comment: where is the `name` value? i dont see it in your code, am i missing something?

Comment: The `name` value came from my props (this.props.module.name)

Comment: i've update my answer, dont forget about controlled and uncontrolled inputs

Comment: just noticed you new comment, glad you figure that out :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, issue is `defaultText`. `defaultText` will assign the default text only on initial rendering it will not update the value. So instead of that assign the props value to `value` property.

Like this:

```
value = {this.props.module.name}
```

**Note:** But it will make the field **read-only**, if you don't update the `props` value (state of parent component) in `onChange` method.

Check this example, when you click on text 'Click Me' it will update the state value but text of input field will not change:

```js
class App extends React.Component{
   constructor(){
      super();
      this.state = {a:'hello'}
   }
   
   click(){
      this.setState({a: 'world'},() => {
         console.log('updated value: ', this.state.a)
      })
   }
   
   render(){
      return(
         <div>
            <Child value={this.state.a}/>
            <p onClick={() => this.click()}>Click Me</p>
         </div>
      )
   }
}

class Child extends React.Component{
   render(){
      console.log('this.props.value', this.props.value)
      return(
         <input defaultValue={this.props.value}/>
      )
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: Than you for this example.
I understand that I only used defaultValue to set the value of this field at initilisation but actually, I can't edit the value even if I don't set the attribute "value". I think it's because every time I type something, It re-render the component. However, the name value that I obtain from the parent component doesn't change that's why I can't "edit" this field.
Why do I get the wrong value for the name ?

Comment: **Edit**: I find the answer. I was misundertound the basics of "controlled components" (using the state and the event handler onChange). Thank you !